# Extracting Autocomplete Emails from Outlook 2007

Tags: language-agnostic, winapi, outlook

I need to extract all the emails that show up as autocomplete entries in Outlook 2007. I mostly need to create a list of all the email addresses which I have sent emails to in the past and dump them into excel.

Should I be connecting to Outlook through COM somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of that information is in a file in the local settings with an extension NK2.

> c:\Documents and
>   Settings\{USERNAME}\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Outlook\{USERNAME}.NK2

This [utility](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_autocomplete.html) can read/edit the contents.

The file format itself is explained here: [Google Code debunk2 explanation of NK2 file format](http://code.google.com/p/debunk2/wiki/fileformat)